# SUM for each row and filter result SUM IN $x

Tags: sql, postgresql

My table's data in Postgres:

```
id  user_id sell_amount sell_currency_id    buy_amount  buy_currency_id type    status  date_add
5   2   2.00000000  1   4.00000000  0   0   0   2013-12-15 19:06:40
6   3   2.60000000  1   5.10000000  0   0   0   2013-12-15 19:06:54 
4   1   1.00000000  1   0.80000000  0   0   0   2013-12-15 19:07:05
7   4   4.00000000  1   8.20000000  0   0   0   2013-12-15 19:07:21
8   5   3.00000000  1   6.00000000  0   1   0   2013-12-15 19:07:40
```

I have to select `id`, `user_id`, `sell_amount`, `sell_currency_id` from this table were `status=0` AND `type=0` AND `SUM` to current row IN $x, order by `ORDER BY` `buy_amount/sell_amount ASC`, `date_add ASC`

Result for `$x = 6`

```
id  user_id sell_amount sell_currency_id    SUM(sell_amount)
4   1   1.00000000  1   1.00000000
6   3   2.60000000  1   3.60000000
5   2   2.00000000  1   5.60000000
7   4   4.00000000  1   9.60000000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a cumulative sum, which Postgres offers.  The logic is then a little tricky.  You want the first value that is greater than or equal to `$x`.

```
select id, user_id, sell_amount, sell_currency
from (select id, user_id, sell_amount, sell_currency,
             sum(sell_amount) over (order by buy_amount/sell_amount ASC, date_add ASC) as cumsell
      from table t
      where status = 0 and type = 0
     ) t
where $x <= cumsell and $x > cumsell - sell_amount;
```